# Rearranging Phrases in filename using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to rename batches of files using Powershell from:

```
file name_FACEBOOK POST
file name_TWITTER POST
file name_FACEBOOK EVENT BANNER
```

to

```
FACEBOOK POST - file name
TWITTER POST - file name
FACEBOOK EVENT BANNER - file name
```

The "file name" can be any number of words with spaces. The "file type" can be any number of words with spaces.

My current code:

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '^(\w+)_(\w+)', '$2-$1'}
```

But that's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an issue with your regex. \w matches alphanumerics and the underscore, but you said that your filename can have spaces in it, so it won't match those.

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '^([^_]+)_(.+)', '$2-$1'}
```

The `[^_]` matches any character except underscore instead.

Comment: That's amazing :D

Only problem now is that it's taken the file extension with it... haha.. "FACEBOOK POST.jpg-MTG Eternal Masters"

Comment: I think I fixed it! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the fun of a regex replace as well, but since @matts1 took that, I wanted to find an alternative.

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {"{1} - {0}.{2}" -f $_.Name.Split('_.')}
```

(`.Split()` splits on either character, not both together, so it makes an array of first part, second part, extension, and then string formats them into the new order)

Comment: This works like a charm too! :3 Also takes into account the file extension. Thank you!